# Filling in missing dates, but for dataframe with unique IDs and Ranges

Tags: python, date, missing-data

Recently I had a problem with my data where I had data for dates when a person in my data hacked a site, but not dates on which they did not hack. This issue was further complicated because some days they would have multiple hacks resulting in multiple rows with the same day and I could not aggregate as this would lose information. Furthermore, I could not simply use re-index as every unique ID had their own range of activity (I could not impute dates which were before their first hack or after their last).The goal was to impute these missing dates into the data with missing data for all but the notifier's alias and a "0" in the variable count (which indicated no hack for that day).
I found a way to accomplish this goal in excel, but it had to be done per ID in its own excel file and took about 10_15 minutes, not ideal when you have hundreds of IDs.

sample photo attached of data, and of sample for how to eventually structure data. [data raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzmqB.png)

[data goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goC2m.png)

I and a friend tried multiple different logic approaches in approaching the problem in Python and eventually wound up with this code I want to share with you. It works, its just not efficient, but this is better than not working. I wanted to put this here so that it helps others who might have a similar problem to me and where the simple series approaches are not working. perhaps those of you who code more regularly than I can improve it for others.
Thanks

```
    data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/hoffm/OneDrive/Documents/holidays paper/all hacks to date fill.csv")
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['datexx'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datex'])
    names = pd.unique(df['notifier']) 
    for i in range(len(names)):
        name = names[i]
        new_df = df[df.notifier == name]
        idx = pd.date_range(new_df["datexx"].min(), new_df["datexx"].max())
        for date in idx:
            if date not in new_df["datexx"].unique():
                df.loc[len(df)] = ["", name, "", "", "", "", "", "", 0, "", "", "", "", date]
```